# Redirect change the state of Auth::check() in Laravel 4

Tags: php, apache, nginx, laravel-4, mamp

## Description

I just want to be able to log-in to my application.

---

**routes**

```
// Home Page
Route::get('/','HomeController@showHome');

// Authentication
Route::get('/login',array('as' => 'login', 'uses' =>'AuthController@showLogin'));
Route::post('/login','AuthController@postLogin');
```

---

**AuthController > postLogin()**

```
public function postLogin()
    {

        $input = array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );
        $rules = array(
            'username'  => 'Required',
            'password'  => 'Required'
        );
        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
        if ($validator->passes())
        {

            // Try to log the user in.
            if (Auth::attempt($input))
            {
                $input['status'] = 1;
                
                //if account is disabled
                if (!Auth::attempt($input))
                {
                    Auth::logout();
                    return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors(array('username' => 'Account disabled'))->withInput(Input::except('password'));
                }

                return Redirect::to('/')->with('success', 'You have logged in successfully');
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors(array('password' => 'Password invalid'))->withInput(Input::except('password'));
            }
        }

        return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }
```

`// dd(Auth::user());` <--- I see the Auth::user() object printing out

---

But for some reasons, after the redirect, my `Auth user` is no longer authenticated. My `Auth::check()` start returning `false`

**HomeController > showHome()**

```
public function showHome()
{

    if (Auth::check())
    {
        return View::make('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {

        // This block of code kept executing 
        return View::make('home');
    }
}
```

---

## Question

What else should I check or look into ?

Is this cause by Laravel or Apache ?

How can I debug this?

---

## Update 1

**app/session.php**

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'file',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 10080,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => array(2, 100),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => false,

);
```

---

## Update 2

I updated my session driver to database

Now my Session database has this data

[image]

Then as soon as I the redirect - I got this

[image]

Comment: You edited the answer. Which code is the problematic one??

Comment: I've added my **session** settings

Answer (score 2):

So you said that you could see the user printing out and thats because user logs in so its inside the first if statement (`if (Auth::attempt($input))`) and  prints the user.

Then it comes to this code `$input['status'] = 1;` thats makes the $input an array with 3 fields. One has password, one username and the status.

The Auth::attemp() only requires 2 parameters username and password so by passing $input as parameter you will actually pass username,password and status so the attempt of login won't happen so you will enter `if (!Auth::attempt($input))` and will be logged out.
Now to fix this delete

```
$input['status'] = 1;
//if account is disabled
```

and change the

```
if (!Auth::attempt($input))
```

to

```
if (Auth::user()->status == 1)
```

The complete postLogin Function:

```
public function postLogin()
    {

        $input = array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );
        $rules = array(
            'username'  => 'Required',
            'password'  => 'Required'
        );
        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
        if ($validator->passes())
        {

            // Try to log the user in.
            if (Auth::attempt($input))
            {

                //if account is disabled
                if (Auth::user()->status!=1)
                {
                    Auth::logout();
                    return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors(array('username' => 'Account disabled'))->withInput(Input::except('password'));
                }

                return Redirect::to('/')->with('success', 'You have logged in successfully');
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors(array('password' => 'Password invalid'))->withInput(Input::except('password'));
            }
        }

        return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }
```

if there are still problems change

`'driver' => 'file'` to `'driver' => 'database'` at session.php 
and at .env file change 
`SESSION_DRIVER=file` to `SESSION_DRIVER=database`

Comment: 1)my answer was correct because there were 2 auth::attemp before the editing. You can check the edit.
2) The problem was with being logged in and the $input['status'] = 1 added at the second auth::attemp makes it not true the second if was if(!Auth::attemp($input)) so if you apss more parameters that it needs then it will return false and since it has a NOT before it becomes true and enters the if where was a Auth::logout()
You Should really check more before commenting

Comment: I'm sorry for this confusion. I was trying to clean out unnecessary code for readers.

Comment: You have removed the problematic code so please edit your answer because with the cose you have there is nothing wrong. I mean the edited code

Comment: I placed back the entire code from my `postLogIn()`.

Comment: To show the complete solution can you please tell me what does status mean and do you save it in your user table???

Comment: status. is just something that I store on my users table to keep track of which user is still active.

Comment: I just tested out your suggested new function, it behave the same as the one that I used to have, It kept redirecting me back the '/'. Do you think is it because of this `Redirect::to('/')` ??

Comment: Yes it is because of Redirect::to('/'). What about user. Is he logged in?

Comment: No. Auth::user() is null.

Comment: Can you try changing 'driver' => 'file',
to 'driver' => 'database' at session.php and at .env file change SESSION_DRIVER=file to SESSION_DRIVER=database

Comment: Next run php artisan session:table  It will create the session table in database. And then migarte. php artisan migrate

Comment: The problem you had is solved now since it rendered the dashboard view. The question about Auth::check() is solved. This is another problem that is related to views and not to login anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127629/discussion-between-leli-1337-and-ihue).

Comment: It's not solved, because the my Authenticated status change state from true to false during the redirect and that is exactly what I am trying to fix.

Comment: since it redirects to dashboard it is solved. To try please add `return Auth::user();` at first line of `showHome`. If the user is returned then it is ok

Comment: If I do `return Auth::user();` I get the `Auth::user()` printing out - no problem since the beginning. But after the application redirect the `state` of my `Auth::user();` **changed !!!** - I'm trying so hard for a couple days now trying to find out why it did that.

Comment: I still facing issue.

Comment: if you get user at showHome() the problem is not with login anymore or with session. It might be something else maybe a problem at you dashboard view. That what the error says now.

Comment: At dashboard view (means user is logged in and stays logged in since you redirect user there in case s logged in) you get the error "Trying to get property of non-object" meaning you are doing something wrong there.
Thats why i said that this question was solved. Anyway post the dashboard view so i can see it.

Comment: No, I have the exact same code base on production server working flawlessly, and I log-in perfectly fine. I highly doubt that there is something wrong with my view.

Comment: the error you have posted with your Update 2 says you are having error there. Thats why i'm saying you might have the problem there.

Comment: I understand why u think that because the error there. But the actual main reason why it cause error because I try to access to auth user object in my view. Auth user object is not accessible because it is null. Why is it null ? That's why I ask this question.

Comment: If you get the user in showHome() then you can pass the user as a parameter to the view. This might sort things out

Comment: I don't get the user in showHome(). I kept getting null.